# graphics.h install issues manjaro

Tags: c, manjaro, bgi

I'm currently attempting to install graphics.h on manjaro, but the library doesn't seem to work. Currently I am getting the following errors when I try running the following code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<graphics.h>
int main()
{
    int gd = DETECT, gm;
    initgraph(&gd, &gm, NULL);

    circle(50, 50, 30);

    delay(500000);
    closegraph();
    return 0;
}
```

```
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccm2VUMu.o: in function `main':
circle.c:(.text+0x32): undefined reference to `initgraph'
/usr/bin/ld: circle.c:(.text+0x46): undefined reference to `circle'
/usr/bin/ld: circle.c:(.text+0x55): undefined reference to `delay'
/usr/bin/ld: circle.c:(.text+0x5a): undefined reference to `closegraph'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I installed graphics.h from the arch user repository using yay, and have made sure to install it's dependencies (guile, sdl, sdl_image), so I'm not sure where to go next.

Comment: Did you try adding the `-lgraph` switch?

Comment: First of all, this "graphics" header and library you're trying to use is originally an old DOS-era thing. It's outdated and not maintained in any way. Even the reimplementations I've seen haven't been touched in years. Secondly, and to solve your problem, you need to link with the actual library itself. There should be either a library file ending in `.a`, or an object file ending in `.o`.

Comment: Where is function `delay()` to be found? Edit -- in the winbgim implementation of BGI graphics.

Comment: thanks, @JustASimpleLonelyProgrammer, worked a treat. Only remaining problem is that the graph window will refuse to close. Is that a general issue or is there still something I'm missing?

Comment: Did you wait for 500 seconds?

Comment: @JohnDent You're welcome and actually I've never used `graphics.h` so I don't know much about this library and it's issues, perhaps the other members of SO can help you with this problem. Also as Weather Vane said, your code is waiting for 500 seconds since you're using `delay(500000)`.

Comment: Are you using [WinBGIm](https://winbgim.codecutter.org/) library built from source code?